# Text inside AppCompatTextView is out of bounds

Tags: android

I have an AppcompatTextView with properties as shown in xml code below. The thing is that this view goes out of bounds as shown on the image. How can I solve this issue?

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/playertwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.13"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/player"
            android:textColor="?attr/main_color_reverse"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:fontFamily="@font/phenomena_bold" />
```

[image: textview]

If any additional information needed please let me know

**EDIT**

a full block of layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="?attr/background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/sides_margin"
        android:weightSum="18">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/playerone"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.13"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/player"
            android:textColor="?attr/main_color_reverse"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"

            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"

            app:fontFamily="@font/phenomena_bold" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player1sign"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/x_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/x_underlined_dt">


        </ImageView>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/player2sign"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:contentDescription="@string/o_desc"
            android:src="@drawable/o_underlined_dt">


        </ImageView>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/playertwo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.13"
            android:lines="1"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/player"
            android:textColor="?attr/main_color_reverse"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="50sp"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:fontFamily="@font/phenomena_bold" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your whole XML code for this screen.

Comment: post you log report

Comment: @ApurvaKolapkar what kind of logs do you need?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, change layout_weight.
But from my point of view, it will better to use ConstraintLayout + horizontal chain, it will be more flexible.